# I cannot install the Cartopy package with any of these functions

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, conda, cartopy

I cannot install the cartopy package when using the `! pip install cartopy` function in Jupyter. I have also tried several alternative functions like `! pip install Cartopy-0.20.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` and `! conda install cartopy` and `! conda install -c conda-forge cartopy` and `!pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts" --global-option="-L C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts" cartopy`. I have also installed all the packages required like `geos`, `proj` and `cython` but still had no success.

I tried everything that I discussed in details section, and I always get this error message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cartopy
  Building wheel for cartopy (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for cartopy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build cartopy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for cartopy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [286 lines of output]
  <string>:90: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.7.2 or later installed, or installation may fail.

(286 lines of output)

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'geos_c.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cartopy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cartopy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: I doubt you got that error message from `conda install`. What was your output there? After installing `geos`, do you have `'geos_c.h'` somwhere on your drive?

Answer (score 0):

On my experiments,I remembered a package update alert  based on  microsoft visual c 14 during cartopy module installation!!(By the way,I must express that my module folder has satisfied requirements for  geospatial analysis)So,I summary that installations as microsoft visual c 14 can cause a risk  for your individual geospatial envThus,I will suggest an alternative solution cartopy